# In Oozie, how I'd be able to use script output

Tags: shell, sh, oozie, oozie-workflow

I have to create a cron-like coordinator job and collect some logs.

```
/mydir/sample.sh >> /mydir/cron.log 2>&1
```

Can I use simple **oozie wf**, which I use for any shell command?
I'm asking because I've seen that there are specific workflows to execute .sh scripts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, you can execute [Shell](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/5.0.0/DG_ShellActionExtension.html) action (On any node in the Yarn cluster) or use the [Ssh](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/5.0.0/DG_SshActionExtension.html) action if you'd like to target specific hosts. You have to keep in mind that the "/mydir/cron.log" file will be created on the host the action is executed on and the generated file might no be available for other Oozie actions.